# JTable grid lines shows after hide it

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am working a billing software development and I have faced some problems during hiding the grid lines I hid my table's grid lines using `tablename.setShowGrid(false)` method.

I have also set background for some specified rows. After hiding grid lines it shows as white lines within the background set rows.

Comment: source code please. Can't imagine what you have tried.

Comment: And where is the sample image?

Comment: i can't add my sample image i am new to stack overflow what can i do

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). *"i can't add my sample image"*  That's probably best for the moment.  It does not take much smarts to realize the form of the problem in this case. 'no grid lines -> grid lines' **got it.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that you set everything visible at the end of the source code. This happend to me too. My advice: Set everything manually visible or not visible. Yeah, that is way more code as usual, but you can see what should be visible and what shouldn't.

I hope I can help you. And I am sorry for my bad English.

Comment: iyour thought is correct.i am using manual renders for grid lines till two days before it worked properly yesterday i just changed UIManager defaults for Menu Items using UIManger.getDeffaultLookAndFeel().put() method after this i am facing the particular problem

Comment: hey can u help me to add my sample images during the time of adding sample images it shows an error called need at least 10 reputations error

Comment: You can not upload an image. But you can copy the code into the textbox you just answered, mark it an set it as code. The button should be somewhere on the top.

Comment: hello frnd just see my profile picture i have add the sample image as my profile picture